# How to change the path/filename format iTunes organises files

Tags: format, itunes, filepath, file-format

first, I know this is a question is asked very frequently all around the internet. And in 99% the answer is 'it's not possible'.

BUT I'm sure I had a solution once.

I just can't remeber the site. I even can't remember the key words I searched for.

**Question:**

**How can I change/define the path and filename (the format of it) iTunes stores the media, if I let iTunes organise my media?**

I would like to have a format like

```
.../artist/if[album]/artist - title.mp3
```

**I know there is a solution!**

If I remember correctly, I had to change something in a xml file.

Note: It might be, that it's not possible with the current version of iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an actual answer but I used the keywords 'itunes directory structure xml' and got  [Folder Structure in iTunes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4329199?tstart=0).

One link to [About iTunes library files](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201610) shows how to access the xml file and unfortunately also says this:

> The iTunes Library.xml file is no longer used by the latest versions of Apple media applications on OS X Yosemite and later.

Once I had this, I googled 'itunes song artist album directory structure library.xml'. This had many links including [Hacking iTunes](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/11/03/itunes.html) which looks like it covers everything relevant to this subject.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It comes close to what I'm searching for. But I edited not the library file itself. It was an other file saying iTunes how and where to save library elements.

Answer (score 0):

The iTunes library is stored as **XML** in a file called `iTunes Music Library.xml`. Using OSX you can find it using command line or Finder at the path:

[image]

I think you speak about the [XSLT script to generate album listing from iTunes XML](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/itunes-albumlist.html) or the [fantastic iTunes podcast XML generator](http://codepen.io/jon-walstedt/pen/jsIup) (you can find this kind of tool when you searching for "itunes xml generator") but here you can modify your playlist, I knew there is no way to change song filenames.

Unfortunately, as explained in the [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201610), *"The iTunes Library.xml file is no longer used by the latest versions of Apple media applications on OS X Yosemite and later.."* .

In fact, since the `iTunes` version **12.2** the program does not create XML files. But, as explained in the support page, if you want to re-make the XML files you can change this setting by flag this option:

[image]

So , what can be the **solution**? I think you can work with your XML files to change whatever you want with scripts or online tools as explained above, change your song filenames as recommended here below  and , then, try to **rebuild your iTunes library**:

[image]

How to change your song filenames as you wish? You can find tons of multiple filename changer scripts but I think the best you can use is a specific program for Windows called [The godfather](http://www.jtclipper.eu/thegodfather/) (the fact that the program have this name  and I am Italian is a pure coincidence..), maybe there are also other programs like that but this one doing exactly what you are looking for ([some details about it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-itunesgodfather-from-organized-crime-to-organized-music-windows/))

[image]

A good OSX alternative to the godfather for Windows, according to the alternativeTo site, seems [MusicBrainz](http://picard.musicbrainz.org/) which make similar things but I've never tried it.

Comment: What I'm looking for is iTunes rename the files you add to the iTunes library exactly like The godfather does. And also save them in the file structure I want. On my old PC I just drag the files from explorer to iTunes and Itunes added them to library and copied them to the NAS is a specific path artist/album/artist - title.

Comment: So, you have solve your problem, good. If there is some information useful please vote any of the answers, if this thread stay without votes it can be deleted.